# How to Stop Jumping Position fixed element on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please anybody help spend 3 days on this but still stuck. I created a section on my site where am playing video-based scroll position to section but when you scroll to the first section or back to the last section from the bottom side video frame jumps.
actually, I don't know how I make position fixed element to top:0 inside relative container currently I have video frame position: absolute which is top:0 and correct but when I scroll am changing position:absolute to position fixed but that can't work with top:0 because fixed element can't work to the relative container so am adding top:35%
please watch the video here
https://www.loom.com/share/c29a3cadb3dc4420a59baaae072c1cec

and here is the site link
https://qa.modulos.ai/product-overview/

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found your solution!

Remove everything that you have, and remove those classes `not-sticky-top` and `sticky not-sticky-bottom`

**And your main problem is that `body` has `overflow: hidden;` which you must remove so that sticky can work, like [this link](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working) says**

Change your css like this:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 100px; // This is important so that the video doesn't go under the header, you can fine tune it afterwords
  max-width: 100%;
}

.video-side {
  position: relative;
}
```

Don't forget to remove `over-flow: hidden` on `body` and remove all those JS triggers and all other classes on the video element